# How to create a bash command which creates output that exactly mimics a source text file that can be pasted into bash shell where histexpand is on?

Tags: command-history, escape-characters, echo, printf

The goal is to create a bash one line command that can be copied and pasted - for instance published on a web forum - and then patches files. See it as a way to distribute a patch file by copy and paste it to the command line.

On the source system:

1. a patch file is used as input,
2. and another bash command should be used to create the ouput.

Currently this is done via:

```
$ oldifs=$IFS;printf '\n{ ';while IFS= read -r p;do printf 'echo %q; ' "$p";done < custom.patch;printf ' }\n\n';IFS=$oldifs
```

That creates output like:

```
{ 
...
echo \ //=\ require\ xyz.js; 
echo @@\ -81\,7\ +80\,6\ @@; 
echo $' \t\t\tchild.currentlyBackingUp = $(\'.dashboard-currently-backing-up\', element).dashboardBackup({type: this.type});'; 
...
 }
```

This can be used as input in a one line patch command on the target system like:

```
patch < { echo \ //=\ require\ xyz.js; echo @@\ -81\,7\ +80\,6\ @@; ... }
```

So far so good, until the source patch file contains a bang (`!`) character. Then the `printf` creates escaped output like:

```
echo $' \t\t\tif (!cp.user.isMyUserQueryLimited()) {'; 
echo $'-\t\t\t\tif (ui.tab.name === "map-tab" && !serverEnv.queryLimited) {'; 
echo $' \t\t\t\tif (!hosted) {';
```

When pasting such a line to a bash command line, it results in:

```
#-bash: !cp.user.isMyUserQueryLimited: event not found
```

How to programmatically create text stream data using a **bash** command that can be copied and pasted, that outputs a stream of text data, by a command that can be pasted into another bash command prompt where history expansion is enabled (histexpand = on)?

Comment: Look through Stephane's A's to these Q's, I seem to remember him answering a Q very similar to this your. Here's a link to his Q's about `paste`, which I think is what it was about: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A22565+paste

Comment: @slm Thanks for you comment. In Stephane's 31 answers about `paste`, of which 50% I did completely read, I could not find any hints that help me to create text streams that can be pasted.

Comment: @ProBackup I'm confused by the question. It looks like you're generating commands which output the patch file. Why not generate the patch file directly?

Comment: @igal There is a need to change files by **copy from forum and paste into terminal** (as a means of patch distribution and to execute the changes).

Comment: @ProBackup I think I'm still missing something. Do you really need a command to generate `echo` statements? Why not have the command generate the text that gets echoed? It looks like there's an unnecessary intermediate step here.

Comment: @ProBackup I took a crack at it. Let me know whether or not my solution makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by some of the details of your question. In particular, I don't understand why you're generating echo statements. So maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but it sounds like you're looking for a way to apply a patch via a copy-paste command. If so, then you can accomplish this using [heredocs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

Using your notation, I think it would look something like this:

```bsh
patch <<HEREDOC
...
 //= require xyz.js
@@ -81,7 +80,6 @@
            child.currentlyBackingUp = $('.dashboard-currently-backing-up', element).dashboardBackup({type: this.type});
...
HEREDOC
```

Here is a simple example to illustrate the technique.

First create a file:

```bsh
cat <<HEREDOC > file-v1.txt
this is the first line
HEREDOC
```

Now create an updated version of the file (e.g. add a line):

```bsh
cat <<HEREDOC > file-v2.txt
this is the first line
here is a second line
HEREDOC
```

Now compute the patch for the two files:

```bsh
diff -u file-v1.txt file-v2.txt
```

The output should look like this:

```
--- file-v1.txt 2017-10-26 09:53:58.000000000 -0500
+++ file-v2.txt 2017-10-26 09:53:58.000000000 -0500
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 this is the first line
+here is a second line
```

Now here is what your command would look like:

```bsh
patch file-v1.txt <<HEREDOC
--- file-v1.txt 2017-10-26 09:53:58.000000000 -0500
+++ file-v2.txt 2017-10-26 09:53:58.000000000 -0500
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 this is the first line
+here is a second line
HEREDOC
```

You should be able to copy-paste this command into your terminal and execute it. It will update `file-v1.txt` to contain the text of `file-v2.txt`, provided you're in the right directory.

Moreover, the heredoc won't perform the history expansion, as you can verify:

```bsh
cat <<HEREDOC
!!
HEREDOC
```